# Scan directories and display in textview

Tags: java, android

I'm scanning recursively directories , but I want to display scanned file in TextView. I'm using a thread, but I can't display filename in textView.
Can you give me an example how to do that?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run(){
        fw.walk(new File("/"));
    }

}).start();

for (File f : list) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        walk(f);
    } else {
        Log.d("sdf", "File: " + f.getAbsoluteFile());


    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code, What have you tried earlier?

Comment: Are you threatening the application to work properly? :-)

Comment: Sorry @aioobe, had to fix it :P

Comment: The code you're showing isn't related to any TextView so it's impossible to help.

Comment: what ever you are doing but you can not update the UI from non UI thread you have to use handler or call postinvalidate() from non-UI thread.......

Answer (score 1):

Use this code .. It starts from the root directory and recursively iterates over all the directories and subdirectories to print the file names in the text view.

Format the text output accoring to your need. here is the logic...

---

Update : okay, i couldn't resist trying it out myself, here is the working code.

Here is the AsyncTask inner class, define it in the activity where you have your textView, in which you have to show the file names. The AsyncTask class uses the above given function, so keep it as is, in the same activity.

```
private class fileNames extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    TextView tv,tv_temp;
    File f;
    ProgressDialog pg;


    public fileNames(File f,TextView tv, Context c) {
this.f=f;
this.tv=tv;
tv_temp=new TextView(c);
pg =new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

    pg.setTitle("loading");
    pg.show();
}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Start : fileNames : doInBackground");
        printFileNames(f,tv_temp);

        return tv_temp.getText().toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tv.setText(result);
        pg.dismiss();

    }

}
```

Function Definition :

```
public void printFileNames(File fName,TextView tv){
    int count=0;
    if(fName.listFiles()!=null)
    for (File f : fName.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()){

            String name = f.getName();
            System.out.println("Dir:"+ name + "\n" );
            tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+"\n" + "Dir:"+ name + "\n" );
            printFileNames(f, tv);
         }else{
             String name = f.getName();
             System.out.println("    File:"+ name +"\n" );
                tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+ "    File:"+ name +"\n" );
                count++;

         }

    }
    }
```

put this code anywhere in the Activity,[in your onCreate(),say ] :

```
TextView fileNameTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thisfile);
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
new fileNames(sdCardRoot,fileNameTextView ,YourCurrentActivity.this).execute();
```

Comment: I know how to scan directories, but I want to display the name of scanned file in TextView.

Comment: I have 2 classes: MainActivity and FileScanner. I call FileScanner's method (that scan directories) in thread and I want to display the name of file in Textview(ex R.id.thisfile). How can I do that?

Comment: It scans only the files(not the directories);

Comment: The class that I'm using scans recursively directories, but it blocks UI.

Comment: this edit will do your job, with a little edit according to your need and logic :-)

Comment: yes, it might if your directory structure is large. use this code in the`doInBackground()` method of the AsyncTask class to avoid blocking the UI.
Update the textView in `onProgressUpdate()` if you want to update the text view incrementally, or in `onPostExecute()` if you want to do it at once.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html